# Shaping theorem for MDPs

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I need help with understanding the shaping theorem for MDPs. Here's the relevant paper: [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pabbeel/cs287-fa09/readings/NgHaradaRussell-shaping-ICML1999.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Epabbeel/cs287-fa09/readings/NgHaradaRussell-shaping-ICML1999.pdf) it basically says that a markov decision process that has some reward function on transitions between states and actions R(s, a, s') has the same optimal policy as a different markov decision process with it's reward defined as R'(s, a, s') = R(s, a, s') + gamma*f(s') - f(s), where gamma is the time-discount-rate.

I understand the proof, but it seems like a trivial case where it breaks down is when R(s, a, s') = 0 for all states and actions, and the agent is faced with the path A -> s -> B versus A -> r -> t -> B. With the original markov process we get an EV of 0 for both paths, so both paths are optimal. But with the potential added to each transition we get, gamma^2*f(B)-f(A) for the first path, and gamma^3*f(B) - f(A) for the second. So if gamma < 1, and 0 < f(B), f(A), then the second path is no longer optimal.

Am I misunderstanding the theorem, or am I making some other mistake?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic here, it's not about programming. You could ask this question on [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Fair enough. I didn’t know how directly related to programming question need be.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about RL theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reinforcement-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the assumption that for **every terminal, and starting state** s_T, s_0 we have f(s_T) = f(s_0) = 0. (Note, that in the paper there is an assumption that after terminal state there is always the new starting state, and the potential "wraps around).

Comment: Where is this assumed in the paper?

Comment: It is done indirectly, paper assumes that your episodes **never end** (alternatively there would be the "absorbing state s0" for which they do not let you define potential. This means, that either all of your trajectories are infinite (not your case) or you need to have these extra absorbing states with no potential. Starting state potential can be anything but assuming it is 0 is just making math easier.

Comment: Ok. I see how assuming f(s_T) = f(s_0) = 0 makes the math work out, but if f(s_0), f(s_T) != 0, then different length paths will have different potentials for 0 <= gamma and gamma != 1.

Comment: Correct. This is incorrect use of potentials

Comment: Thanks! I don’t yet have enough points to upvote you, but I would if I could.